# Android - What's the correct file path to use when uploading to server

Tags: android, android-image

I'm trying to take a photo, store it locally and synchronize with server later. But when I'm trying to upload it, logcat says there's no such file in directory. But when I check it via the file manager, the image is there

This is how I'm giving the path to upload to server

```
private static final String INITIAL_CAPTURE_TITLE = "upgrade.jpeg";

private Uri getImageUri(String item_no){

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), item_no + "_up_" + INITIAL_CAPTURE_TITLE);
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    return imgUri;
}
```

By using this, the path is given like this I think

```
/file:/storage/emulated/0/ku193_up_upgrade.jpeg
```

The file is actually there, but it still gives me an exception.

EDIT : This is the exception I'm getting

```
04-20 15:02:24.909: W/System.err(27641): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/ku193_up_upgrade.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: The file name is: `ku193_up_upgrade.jpeg`?

Comment: Yes, it is. Never mind the problem though. I got over that problem by using another method to set image URI

Comment: So, please add your answer and mark it as accepted.